# Is it possible to retrieve private photos from facebook after logging in?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have on my website login with facebook.

After logging in I get a permit for access to information.

Can I retrieve private photos after logging in?

Comment: AFAIK photos are only "private" in the sense that their URL on the Facebook servers is not know to you. Therefore if you use the [Authentication process](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) to obtain the correct [permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) (in your case, "user_photos" should suffice), you will be able to access the user's albums and photos. In Javascript this would be achieved by calling `FB.api('/me/photos')` or `FB.api('/USER_ID/photos')` depending upon context

Comment: @LeeSibbald I've tried this FB.api('/USER_ID/photos') and this error: "A user access token is required to request this resource." Why?

Comment: Most likely because you are trying to identify a user by ID and Facebook needs to know you have a valid access token for that user, and for the action you are trying to take. Try this: FB.api('/USER_ID_HERE/photos?access_token=YOUR_TOKEN_HERE'). Also did you try the '/me/photos' version?

Comment: @LeeSibbald How can i get the access_token for specific USER?

Comment: The specific user has to put through the authentication process by your app - check out the link in my original reply

Comment: Can i view the photos from another user? Or I can just my photos? Thank you.

Comment: @LeeSibbald This code works correctly: FB.api('/me/photos?access_token=' + accessToken, function(response) { }); I need to retrieve the photos from another user - is that possible?

Comment: It is possible to view another user's photos so long as the other user has also been through your app's authentication flow, and granted the required permissions. In this case you would probably want to exchange the first token you receive (which only lasts 1-2 hours) for a longer term token https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/ (lasts 60 days) and save that for later use

Comment: @LeeSibbald Can you help me - how can i get the photos from another user? Can you give me the example? How can i get the access token from another user? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry John, I've helped you rather a lot already and I have my own work to do - the rest of the information you need is in the several links I have shared with you already. Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it can't. Best way to find out for sure is to set up a test user, and see if your access token will let you find private pictures in the [Graph Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).